# use prebuild libcurl.a with my android project

Tags: android, android-ndk, libcurl

I have libcurl.a compiled for armeabi, armeabi-v7a and x86. I want to include it in my android project and successfully execute this [simple code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html), The problem is I'm not quite sure what to write in android.mk and application.mk to make it happen!

I have written this so far: Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_Hazem_test_Hazem.c
LOCAL_MODULE:= com_Hazem_test_Hazem
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

kindly, help me figure out the contents of those two files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include these lines after `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)` and before the part that uses the libcurl

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := curl_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := <path>/libcurl.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := <path>/curl/include


include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and to use:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += curl_static
```

Comment: ok Alex, how do I present my pre-built libs in the file system under the jni folder?
and where does the last line (LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES) goes at the end of the android.mk file?
should I leave application.mk as it is?

Comment: The lib goes to ojb/local/armeabi, but your lib and include files could be in any where, because it is a static lib.

Comment: but note that the ndk-build places the lib in that folder that said, <path> can be any path in your system, not android system.

Comment: I am getting (Undefined Reference to 'x') whenever I try to compile the code, why? am I missing something?